# problem with moving a file iinto another folder

Tags: python, string, operating-system, callable

I have this code to move an item into another folder

```
import os
    

files = os.listdir('C:/Users/EL127032/youtube-downloader-converter')
print(files)
numbertocheck = 0
numberoftimes = len(files)

while numbertocheck != numberoftimes:
    if any("mp3" in s for s in files):
        filechecking = files[numbertocheck]
        if "mp3" in filechecking():
            oldfilepath = ("C:/Users/EL127032/youtube-downloader-converter/" + filechecking)
            newfilepath = ("C:/MuziekMP3/" + filechecking)
            os.rename(oldfilepath, newfilepath)
    numbertocheck = numbertocheck + 1
```

But when i run this i get

```
  File "C:\Users\EL127032\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    if "mp3" in filechecking():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 12 (as suggested by the error message) you have:

```py
...
if "mp3" in filechecking():
...
```

The parentheses after `filechecking` will make the interpreter assume that it is a function that needs to be called.

However, `filechecking` is a `str` (string) that contains the file name you are interested in.

Simply remove the `()` or change it to something like:

```py
...
if filechecking.endswith(".mp3"):
...
```

and try again.